# Prevent date input field from getting emptied on hover JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I am working on an A/B test and I need to convert an input text to a date. I have created a function to perform this conversion only on hover, so it does not cause any issues when submitting the form. However, the problem is that when I hover over the input again, it resets the value and leaves the input field empty. This could be frustrating for users, and I am trying to find a solution, but I have not been able to find one yet.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var inputField = document.getElementById("dateinput");
  
  inputField.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    inputField.type = "date";
  });
  
  inputField.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    inputField.type = "text";
    if (inputField.value) {
      var date = new Date(inputField.value);
      // Adjust the date with the timezone offset
      date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + date.getTimezoneOffset());
      var formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
        month: "2-digit",
        day: "2-digit",
        year: "numeric",
      });
      inputField.value = formattedDate;
    } else {
      // Set the input field value to "Date Final Product Needed" if no date is selected
      inputField.value = "Date Final Product Needed";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dateinput" placeholder="Date Final Product Needed">
```

Comment: Why are you even doing it this way i.e why are you converting the types of `input`?

Comment: Per client request, the problem is that I am working with an A/B test and I have to do this via DOM, I can't directly change the input type from HTML

Comment: do one thing instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout` use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by swapping out the mouseover event for focus, and mouseout for blur.